# npx - what does the `@` do in `npx prettier` vs `npx prettier@2`?

Tags: node.js, shell, prettier, npx

I'm familiar with `node_modules/.bin` and the `npx` tool.

I've recently noticed one of our configs runs:

```
npx prettier@2
```

Which actually produces different output from

```
npx prettier
```

It seems like prettier is using a different config file when called this way.

**What does the `npx prettier@2` do differently from `npx prettier`?**

**Edit**:

As requested:

```
$ npx prettier --version
2.1.1

$ npx prettier@2 --version
npx: installed 1 in 1.437s
2.2.0
```

Prettier 2.2.0 was [released a few hours ago](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/releases/tag/2.2.0) and [seems to have a bug](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9738)

Comment: One uses whatever the default version is and the other forces prettier to semantic version 2.

Comment: @zero298 do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Yes, [npx docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) `npx [options] <command>[@version] [command-arg]...`

Comment: Thanks @zero298!  There's only one `node_modules/.bin/prettier` file - and `node_modules/prettier/package.json` says it's prettier 2. So why does the `@2` command produce a different result?

Comment: PS you're welcome to add an answer and I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the question now.  I didn't realize that `prettier@2` essentially *is* latest, which is what you would think you would get without the `@`.  I'm not sure why you get different results.  Can you run `npx prettier --version` and `npx prettier@2 --version` and see if you get different versions?  Maybe you have a different locally cached version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npx` will cause a package to be downloaded and execute `bin` scripts provided by that package.  The command `npx prettier` will cause the latest version of the prettier to be downloaded and the file [`./bin/prettier.js`](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/2381f5aedb47dbc3ab005ac82d4ea08f1ba6dce0/bin/prettier.js) will be executed.

`npx` also allows you specify which specific semantic version you want to download with the `@` notation.  So `npx prettier` runs latest, but `npx prettier@2` will still run only version 2 even when prettier updates to a new major version.

See [npx package docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx):

```
npx [options] <command>[@version] [command-arg]...
```

and

> `-p, --package <package>` - define the package to be installed. This
> defaults to the value of `<command>`. This is only needed for packages
> with multiple binaries if you want to call one of the other
> executables, or where the binary name does not match the package name.
> If this option is provided `<command>` will be executed as-is, without
> interpreting @version if it's there. Multiple `--package` options may
> be provided, and all the packages specified will be installed.

---

A somewhat deeper look at your question makes things a little bit weirder though.  I'm unsure why you get different results when you run both commands, they should be equivalent (right now at least since 2 is the current major version).

Try printing the version string with both and see if you get a difference, that might show some additional details

```
npx prettier --version
npx prettier@2 --version
```

Both give me the same string, but that might be different depending on your cache or config.

Comment: Added the results to my answer! It looks like prettier 2.2 doesn't use my prettier config file, but prettier 2.1 does.